# X11 cannot write .ICEauthority file on a vmhgfs partition

Tags: mount, xorg, shared-folders, vmware-fusion

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 in a virtual machine using VMWare Fusion.

I changed my home folder so that it is shared with the host OS. I.e. `/home/<user>` is now mounted automatically at boot time by adding the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
.host:/<user> /home/<user> vmhgfs defaults,uid=<user>,gid=<user> 0 0
```

After making this change, I cannot login anymore on my session as X11 complains about being unable to update the `/home/<user>/.ICEauthority`. I can rm the old file, recreate it, etc. but nothing will do. The `.ICEauthority-c` file is created properly so this is *not* a permission issue on my home folder.

My guess is that this particular file is created using exotic flags that this filesystem ignore/do not support and this leads to this failure.

I found workaround which is creating a `.gnomerc` file in my home folder containing:

```
export ICEAUTHORITY="/tmp/.ICEauthority-${USER}"
```

...but I would prefer to avoid using this work-around.

I have two questions:

a. Is there a way to fix this issue permanently without relying on this workaround?

b. I think it may be related to the mount flags. What are the recommended flags to mount a home partition using vmhgfs?